# $_SESSION['user'] not working

Tags: php, session-variables

SO this is the code for logging and and where I set things

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = "kjkj";
    $_SESSION['pass'] = "";  
    $error = $user = $pass = "";

    if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
        $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);

     if ($user == "" || $pass == "") {
            $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
     } else {
            $query = "SELECT store,c_pass FROM store
                    WHERE store='$user' AND c_pass='$pass'";

            if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0) {
                $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
            } else {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            $str = $_SESSION['user'] . ", You are now logged in. Please 
                       <a href='scheduler.php'>click here</a>.";

                die($str);
            }
        }
    } ?>
```

It'll print the correct store name after the query and all that. But when I try to use it in another php file like this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    die("<p><h1>Please Login</h1></p>");
} else {
    echo "<p><form id ='addemp' method=\"post\" action=\"addUser.php\">
          Name<input type=\"text\" name=\"emp\" />
      \"". $_SESSION['user'] . "\">
      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"AddUser\" />
    </form></p>";
}
```

It is an empty string. Not null just empty string. I tried all the solutions I can find on the internet, none of them worked. I'm out ideas as to why this isn't working.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you put session_start() in your second file?

Comment: try running a var_dump on $_SESSION to see what it looks like are various points in your code. Switching files should not blow away session data as far as I know

Comment: start_session() was added to second file as well

Comment: I would suggest reading a tutorial on user management such as http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/PHP-Membership-System/67102 The way you got it now is extremely fragile and prone to bugs and security holes. Also OWASP is your friend. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_PHP_Project

Comment: You should only be running session_start() once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a number of things. First of all do sessions work any other time? 
I don't think you have provided enough information for us to help you. It could be a problem with set-up of apache/php not just your code. Has happened to me before when I was developing on Windows with WAMP and temp folder didn't have correct permissions. As I said there could be many issues that cause your session to misbehave.

- When you do a counter and refresh
  page does it keep a number?
- At the
  **beginning** of every time that uses sessions you need to have
  session_start() method called.
  **Important: There can't be any echo's or prints etc before
  session_start().**
- Put `var_dump($user)` before `$_SESSION['user'] = $user;` and check the content of $user before it gets saved. It could be that your sanitizing function is not working properly. Do it also at the end of the first script to see the content of `$_SESSION` to make sure variables are saved properly.

Comment: I'm using fatcow.com for my domain and server, So I thinks it's been setup correctly. session_start() was added first thing in my code.

Comment: @Monir if you `var_dump` at the end of first file (the file that sets all sessions). Can you see correct values? If you can then create a new file just with `<?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); ?>` to see if you can actually see expected values.

Comment: Also if I were you I would do a quick test. Setup file set.php with `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['test'] = "works"; ?> <a href="get.php">Go to get</a>` and one called get.php with `<?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); ?>`. Then go to set.php and click Go to get link to see if you see the `test=>works`.

Comment: Ok, I ran var_dump and for login, everything works. for the other file, i get very strange error. It works sometimes for the var_dump at the beginning of a file, sometimes doesn't. Where I need the user, it never works. Trying your test now

Comment: Ok, that tests works, also I realized that the $_SESSION['pass'] always works. It just the user don't work. How can I destroy the session everytime the user closes the connection, i.e. leaves my site?

Comment: session is only open while browser is open (as far as I can remember). In my last module I implemented cookie so person could be logged in for a week and when they were coming back I would check their encrypted and hashed cookie to make sure they are who they say they are. However if someone presses Logout I just simply do `unset($_SESSION['user');` and `unset($_SESSION['pass');`. It would be easier for you if you created an object called login that holds just variables such as login, login_date etc. (no methods etc) and you can just serialize it to `$_SESSION['login'];`

Comment: using object and serialization would make your code a bit more cleaner and easier to follow by other people. later on if you need to add extra field you just modify "login class" rather than fiddle with setting/un-settings correct session indexes. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`. Also note that keeping the password in the session is a very BAD practice and a BIG security hole.

Answer (score 0):

If you claim to have inserted session_start() in that page too, do 2 things:

1) correct your html, this line.

```
echo "<p><form id ='addemp' method=\"post\" action=\"addUser.php\">
          Name<input type=\"text\" name=\"emp\" />
      \"". $_SESSION['user'] . "\">
```

Has something not really clear. Where do you echo your $_SESSION to? is it maybe that your browser fails at rendering it? What did you want to accomplish? It can be that the browser is interpreting wrong that closing tag `>`. Try tidying html first.
If that was meant to be the input field value, write

```
Name <input type=\"text\" name=\"emp\" value=\"".$_SESSION['user']."\"/>
```

2) var_dump the $_SESSION['user'] to see if it's really an empty string.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    die("<p><h1>Please Login</h1></p>");
} else {
    var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
}
```

Comment: 1) that was for debugging purpose, i removed it soon after. var_dump revealed even stranger problem, check comments under luke's answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the OP had an issue with register_globals.

In php.ini set `register_globals = Off`, then try the code again.

I had the exact same problem - I had a user variable in the session, and then set `$user = array();` and found that the `$user` variable was overwriting the `$_SESSION['user']` variable. Disabling register_globals fixed it.

Or you can change your $user variable to something like $myUser, but it's better to disable register_globals anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @kpaulsen answer,

I got same situation on him, $variable overwrites $_SESSION['variable'] so I followed his suggestion but it isn't works fine on me then I found out another way of setting the register_globals = Off

Add this line on .htaccess

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a issue I had some time ago, made all the code perfectly, but forgot to insert the `session_start();` at the connection script, witch receives the log-in `$_POST['somevariable']` to validate with the DB.

On resume, don’t forget to start a session at your connection.